# Google Charts: Maps and Tabbed Webpages

Tags: 2007, mapping-engine

I want to try and do something quite interesting and challenging that combines the features of Google Charts (see last 5 Olympic Hosts http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/new_map_charts.html), particularly the heat maps and easy tabs (or something similar) so that:

When a user clicks on a particular region, (eg Australia) then below the map, the user receives a list of all the products we trade including a few product details based upon information in a SharePoint list elsewhere in the site.

I want it also so that when the user clicks on North America, the same happens, but the user only sees the NA products and the Aus ones disappear.

Hope this is possible, as I think it will look pretty cool if it comes off.

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint, but I reckon this could be easier done in Silverlight (I think) you can define polygons which respond to an Onclick event and populate an area on your page with the data you want.

Having said that, you'd probably need to use the Client Object model, which is SP2010 only.

Comment: thanks James, but we have 2 problems: the Silverlight plug in isn't standard software within the firm and we have SharePoint 2007 (Basic)

Comment: Ok then. What you could do then is to add listener events to trap click events (See: http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/events.html) to get a relevantly clicked region, and combine it with SPServices jQuery library (see: http://spservices.codeplex.com/) to get/update the relevant list items.